# How can I parse a progressive JPG

Tags: parsing, jpeg, progressive

I am writing a 'clean-room' program that requires parsing/unparsing of jpegs.  I have found all the information I need to parse/unparse baseline jpegs, but I cannot find the information that I need to parse/unparse progressive jpegs.

I need to be able to convert the compressed data to macroblocks and back, so most available frameworks are too high level.  I also want to understand what is going on, hence the 'clean room' approach.

Can anybody help me please? A specification of the SOF1 header would be useful, as would be the layout of the compressed data in the scan segment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oooops, I seem to have mispoken.  I need to understand an SOF2 header, not an SOF1 header.  Sorry.

Comment: I have and example of an SOF2 header - it has 17 bytes of data which are: [8, 3, -128, 6, 64, 3, 1, 34, 0, 2, 17, 1, 3, 17, 1].

Comment: type: 194
data size: 17
data: [8, 3, -128, 6, 64, 3, 1, 34, 0, 2, 17, 1, 3, 17, 1]

This gives

precision: 8
height: = 896
width: =  1600

3 components 
1, 34, 0  id1, hSample 2 vsample 2
2, 17, 1  id2, hSample 1 vsample 1
3, 17, 1  id3, hSample 1 vsample 1

Comment: The data above gives

precision: 8
height: = 896
width: =  1600

3 components 
1, 34, 0  id1, hSample 2 vsample 2
2, 17, 1  id2, hSample 1 vsample 1
3, 17, 1  id3, hSample 1 vsample 1

Comment: The header structures are the same for all frame types.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to figure this out, I'd get this book:

[https://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1486949641&sr=8-5&keywords=jpeg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604434)

It explains it all in easy-to-understand terms. The author has source code at

http://colosseumbuilders.com/sourcecode/imagelib403.zip

that is designed to be easy to understand.

The SOF1 header is the same as all other SOF headers. You need to have a copy of the JPEG standard (as obtuse as it is). The other sources above will help you get through it.

Comment: This would be an acceptable comment to the original question. It is not, however, an answer.

Comment: It did prod me to investigate with a byte-inspector and find out that the assertion was true and that I could actually continue in partial ignorance.  So thanks for the nudge

Comment: The problem you have is that in order to parse a JPEG stream, you largely need to decode it. You can examine the blocks. A progressive scan has the format and restart markers as a sequential scan but getting to the actual data is tough.

Comment: I thank you for confirming that - I had begun to suspect that it was the case.

I have analysed a SOF2 header and it *does* match the layout of the SOF0 header.
I now have a problem in that I can only find two huffman tables when I would ecpect four (AC/DC for luminance/chromiance.

As for the order of the blocks - oddly enough it matters not for my program.  If the only difference is that they appear in a convoluted order then I am good-to-go as soon as I find my missing Huffman Tables.

Comment: The number of huffman tables is specified in the other blocks. There does have to be 4 tables. THere are usually at least 2.